# how can we set DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN=0?

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2019, chromium, depottools, source-depot

While fetching the chromium, I get an issue as its asking me to set the `DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN=0` in my local machine.

[image]

So that I can make the changes in the Chromium browser. Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run this command from the command line window that you are planning to build Chromium from:

```
set DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN=0
```

now do your Chromium compilation after executing the above command.